# Zuul reverse proxy and Spring boot admin configuration

Tags: spring-boot, netflix-zuul, spring-boot-admin

I have a microservice architecture with 6 services.
- Eureka
- Zuul as a reverse proxy
- Spring boot admin
- ...

All these microservices are dockerized and run on AWS.

My problem is, I want spring admin to be behind zuul and hit it with 
xxx.xxx.x.x:8762/admin

Only the port 8762 is exposed, and when I try to get spring admin it redirect me to 
xxx.xxx.x.x:9101/admin/login

I would like spring admin to pass by Zuul for example returning me
xxx.xxx.x.x:8762/admin/login

My zuul config is the following:

```
# Admin configuration
zuul.routes.admin-server.path=/admin/**
zuul.routes.admin-server.service-id=admin-service
zuul.routes.admin-server.strip-prefix=false
```

How can I configure this ?
I dont have this behavior with the others microservice, 
if I call xxx.xxx.x.x:8762/microservice-1/task
I get xxx.xxx.x.x:8762/microservice-1/task in return

Thanks.